# Write a program which takes input from console and display the output in a webpage without using database

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to Write a C# program which takes input from console and display the output in a webpage without using database (Web server can be used) ?
one c# and one asp file should be there.

Comment: What you are going to write is called CGI app (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question lacks detail. What did you try so far, what was the result? Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: No this is not a homework, This is something i want to include in my project but i am not able to do so. I am new to ASP,I have done similar kind of thing in java and Jsp though.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I would create a webpage which supports two modes:

a) input mode - a client can post to the page and pass a parameter value. The value is then stored in a shared container (or static variable)

b) output mode - a client requests the page and the value from the shared container (static variable) is displayed

I would then create a console application ("input from console" means a console application?) that posts to the page using the `WebRequest` class and passes the parameter read from the console.

Comment: It is like we have 2 applications running. 1 C# program to take input from the user and 1 separate ASP application which displays the input on the web page.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be done. I can't provide you correct code right now, but the idea is simple and it can have different implementations.

1) Create console application that uses HttpWebRequest class to send parameters to your page using GET or POST (POST requires about five additional code lines to put the content).

2) Create ASPX page, that in page_load method checks if data exists in GET/POST and if yes, it stores it in Application. When data not exists in GET/POST, it checks if data exists in ASP.NET Application Object, and if yes shows it. Page should auto refresh and some period of time, or use AJAX to load new messages.

3) You can create the same thing for sending messages back to console, by making request from console application with "special" command to get new messages, that page stores in Application.

The same thing may be done using ASMX web services or WCF. The whole "trick" in the solution, to make request in console application with intervals or to refresh page or using AJAX or full postback to retrieve new messages.
With WCF (not only) console application may be implemented without the need to make request with intervals.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for responding. I have tried the first part and i am able to read the data from the file and display it in a console application (C# application), But the second part i.e. retrieving data from the method and display it on the webpage is not working somehow. Could you please tell me how do we do that. I am new to ASP.net.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at these

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
p.Start();
// Do not wait for the child process to exit before
// reading to the end of its redirected stream.
// p.WaitForExit();
// Read the output stream first and then wait.
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555134